# Show a short link for Answers too... not just Questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, permalink

Currently, when you hover over the `link` link for a question you see a shortlink.

For example for **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664462/ajax-inconsistency-in-ie-8)**, hovering over the `link` for the question shows you:

> [AJAX inconsistency in IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3664462/[USER_ID])

and the title displays `short permalink to this question`

Whereas hovering over the `link` for an answer for the same question shows you

> [AJAX inconsistency in IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664462/ajax-inconsistency-in-ie-8/3664482#3664482)

and the title displays `permalink to this answer`

I think it'd be very convenient to provide a short permalink to the answers too. For example the above answer can also be linked to by simply using

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/3664482

**As Jon Seigel pointed out in the answers, the above takes you directly to the Answer, and it's just as short as the question link.** Also, the User ID could be tacked on.

Providing this as the answer `link` seems more consistent to me.

**Visual aids:**

*Question:*

[image]

*Answer:*

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can already mostly do this by abusing the URL processing algorithm, but it's an extra step to get the URL (you'll have to manually edit).

How? When you put in an *answer* post ID into the URL where it expects a *question* ID, you get taken to the answer automatically!

Example linking to Jeff's answer:

Long link (from the "Link" button): [Show a short link for Answers too... not just Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/show-a-short-link-for-answers-too-not-just-questions/63846#63846)

Short link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63846

Using the shorter link, you automatically get redirected to the long link.

<strike>The only way I could see this getting shorter is something like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/p/ ('p' is for posts) followed by either a question ID or answer ID.</strike> Edit: this is already implemented as /q/.

Comment: That's neat... Also, slightly shorter: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63846

Comment: Works for multi-page also:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63567

Comment: With the user id seems to work but I can't guarantee it'd get logged/counted for the badges obviously:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63567/140548

Comment: @rchern - Yeah, that's what I'd like to know (whether they'd be logged).

Comment: Old news, I've a list with answer links like that in my SO profile. So that it fits within the 3K char limit :) +1 for sharing it though.

Answer (score -1):

think we wish to have more people share links to questions rather the answers,  we wish people to promote the site, not just their answer.

Comment: that's an ominous "we"... ;)

Comment: This is interesting.  Someone from my office asked me a question almost the exact same as a question I'd answered on Stack Overflow.  So rather than writing a detailed explanation for them via email, I sent them the link to my answer.