# Include the question title in the new user-tagged question link, and include them in user profiles

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, linked-questions

Two suggestions regarding the new links:

1. Just now I wanted to hand out a link to an old question of mine, so I went to my user profile and found it in my question list. However, in order to get the link tagged with my user id, I had to actually click through to the question and find the 'link' href. Could user profiles use the new link instead of the older one?
2. Could the question title (the arbitrary verbiage that follows the question id) be included in the user-tagged links? It is very helpful for readers to identify the content it contains, and would increase clickthroughs in environments where bare URLs are all that are seen (e.g. IRC channels).

Comment: Maybe you should provide a context as to what new links.... I seem to remember a sharing links post announcing some new sharing link Badges, but I think it only applies to Beta sites (not Stackoverflow)... is this the case? Are these the new links you are referring to?

Comment: @Peter The pestering pop-ups that may show up will only apply to sites in a public beta. The badges themselves, and the linking system, are going to be present at all times - 3 bronze and 1 silver are already awarded on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Grace Note - Thanks for the clarification. I see now that Question links have my user ID attached.... however I don't see how I can get a link to an Answer that has my user ID attached.

Comment: @Peter: yes, they are only for questions -- see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/show-a-short-link-for-answers-too-not-just-questions

Comment: I know that short link links are only available for Questions (you linked to my question)... but I'm not sure if the URLs of Answers can have your User ID added to them for tracking?

Answer (score 1):

These both seem like good ideas to me.

Regarding point number 2. If the title lettering is included in the `link` then it seems to change the functionality of the Question `link` which currently reads: `short permalink to this question`... in other words, including the title lettering would make the link long. So maybe some sort of added functionality should be worked out for that suggestion.