# Can a user-tagged link be created to an answer? (for purposes of announcer, booster, publicist)

Tags: discussion, badges, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show a short link for Answers too… not just Questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/show-a-short-link-for-answers-too-not-just-questions)

You can easily get a link to a question that is tagged with your id, for purposes of getting the Announcer, Booster, or Publicist badge.  You can also easily get a link to a specific answer.

But can you get a link (either easily or by manually constructing it) to a **specific answer**, that is also tagged with your user number for purposes of getting those 3 linky badges?

Comment: If you [do it manually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64018/how-and-when-does-the-tracking-of-shared-links-work/64030#64030) (see comments), sure. Otherwise, this is already [status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/show-a-short-link-for-answers-too-not-just-questions).

Answer (score -2):

Let me check...

yes look here, right below the `v`s. It's a permalink to your answer!

vvvvvv

Comment: That doesn't have a user tag, however, which is what this question is asking for.