# Visits aren't tracked from referral URLs using answer IDs 

Tags: bug, status-completed, publicity-badges

The `/q/post_id/user_id` form used for the questions' sharing/referral links seems to also work for answers. For example, when I go to [`/q/64030/1`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64030/1) I am redirected to [`/questions/64018/#64030`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64018/#64030). I use this feature quite a bit and I've just noticed that clicks on such links do not seem to be tracked for the purposes of the publicity badges (announcer, booster, publicist).

I submitted [Shirlock Homes's answer on DIY about measuring the height of a tree](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/is-there-an-easy-way-to-measure-the-height-of-a-tree/7110#7110) to Reddit, where [it got 60 votes and appeared on the front page of r/DIY](http://www.reddit.com/r/DIY/comments/lxeux/a_clever_old_logger_technique_to_easily_measure/). It must have got at least the required 25 visits, but 30 hours later I still haven't been awarded the announcer badge. In the same time frame I submitted another link to Reddit using the question ID, and I got a badge for it, despite it getting a fraction as much attention.

There have been several times in the past where I haven't received an announcer badge that I thought I deserved, and I'm now pretty sure that this was the cause.

edit: Tim Stone pointed out that Jeff confirmed in [How and when does the tracking of shared links work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64018/how-and-when-does-the-tracking-of-shared-links-work/64030#comment-152481) that these links *are* supposed to be tracked.

edit: It's now been <s>five</s> twenty days. I got another Announcer badge on a different site using a question ID, but this one still hasn't been awarded.

Comment: Hmm, Jeff previously [implied that it did work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64018/how-and-when-does-the-tracking-of-shared-links-work/64030#comment-152481), but I don't know what the reality is now.

Comment: Watch out pointing fingers at Rebecca Chernoff... That used to be my favorite pasttime until... um, well, certain tragedy struck... Suffice it to say, she has magical powers. So be warned ;-)

Comment: "shifting blame from Rebecca to Jeff" -- Smart move. [Your kitchen appliances are now probably safer](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/rchern-strikes-back)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException her powers can be limited ... for the right price

Comment: @Zypher DO TELL! I moved to a house without a garbage disposal I was so afraid of her!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [the changes to the publicity badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118509/134300) these are now supported ([confirmation from balpha](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/816147#816147)). This question is now resolved; I was just retroactively granted a Publicist badge for sharing the link.

<s>Quoting [Rebecca Chernoff♦'s answer to a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114607/do-shared-link-to-answers-also-count-for-announcer-booster-publicist-badges):</s>

> No. These badges are specifically for linking to questions like the description says.

So there was a misunderstanding and this is actually [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Answer (score 4):

This really just comes down to the way badges are granted.  Just because a badge runs on one site does not mean that it was run at the same time on another site.  Some of our badges don't run as often as others, so the answer is generally "have patience".

Comment: Upvoting out of fear.... ;-)

Comment: Upvoting out of civic duty.

Comment: Do you have any idea what sort of frequency it runs at for [DIY.se]?

Comment: @JeremyBanks our badges aren't really granted like that.  I can't tell you when it will run next or when it ran last.