# Do shared link to ANSWERS also count for Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges?

Tags: support, badges, publicity-badges

The legends for these badges say

> Shared a link to a **question** that was visited ...

But if I share a link directly to the **answer**, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8361698/684229), does it also count for these badges?

BTW, does it also count if I share the link at StackExchange site? Or must it be outside? This is not written in the legend nor [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/).

**EDIT: Feb 26 2012: It seems links to answers work too??!! 2 days ago I received an [Announcer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer?userid=684229), but [the link pointed to answer](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519028)!!** I don't remember publishing any other link to this question.

Comment: To answer your "BTW" - it has to be shared outside the SE network.

Comment: @ChrisF - But that means I have to participate in fb or twitter, both of which do not interest me.

Comment: @JonH - it could be on Google+ :) or even your own blog. Basically it's anywhere *other* than SE.

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer correct

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the "Recent feature changes" Q/A, since [2012-01-10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/159019) *"[s]haring direct links to answers now also counts towards [the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist] badges"*.

Comment: Is this still valid, I shared an answer link and received no badge yet although the number of views grew substantially for that question.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu The relevant number for the badges is *external* views (which aren't displayed AFAIK).

Answer (score 12):

No, but you can make a link that does.

Share links for questions and answers look like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/<question-id>/<user-id>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/<answer-id>/<user-id>
```

If you take a question link and add an anchor with the answer id at the end, i.e.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/<question-id>/<user-id>#<answer-id>
```

This should both link to the answer *and* count towards referral badges.

Comment: Wow, that's a good trick man! @RebeccaChernoff, can you tell us if this will work?

Comment: @TomasT. It works in most cases ([example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114607#114621)), but it's not an official feature and can fail for the few question that have multiple pages ([example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134#9254)).

Comment: @Jeremy no, I meant if the *accounting for the badge* works, not the link itself :)

Comment: @hammar now I see that it must work because the server won't see the `#<answer-id>` part of the URL! How great!!

Answer (score 10):

At the moment of writing this (December 2011), these badges were specifically for linking to questions like the description says. *(This was changed later, as mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123544/295232).)*

<s>The link must be clicked from outside the network in order for it to count for this purpose.</s> **Editor's note:** As of the 2018 move to HTTPS, clicks from inside the network also count, as it's now impossible to distinguish this.

Comment: Can you comment on the purpose of having the linking user's ID in the URL, if it's not used for this?

Comment: Rebecca, thank you for answer. Wow, that's surprising! I'd expect linking an answer directly is almost the same as linking the whole question, so it is a promotion of StackOverflow anyway... isn't it?

Comment: Is it difficult to have them count? I am as likely to link to an answer as to the specific question - now if I want to badge-chase I need to change my ways. How is that encouraging better behaviour (that is, why does it matter which I link to?)

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense - why should I sign up for facebook or twitter to earn a badge?  I'd rather pass on the badges if I need to sign up to these types of sites.

Comment: @JonH You don't have to sign up anywhere. Sharing on *any* external site would work, or you could email the link to people you know, etc. Plus, strictly speaking you don't have to have the badge either. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear - But the "marketing" behind it says to share the answer or question on fb / twitter / linked..etc.

Comment: @JonH What do you mean by "marketing behind it"?

Comment: @MatthewRead we've discussed behavior changes with these badges, but no changes have been made, and my answer is the way they are currently.

Comment: @Rebecca, if there is a pending proposal to change it (as this discussion suggests, that would be a good thing), please share a link.

Comment: @AnnaLear He means the share to twitter/fb/what-have-you buttons that you find under/next to answers

Comment: @Rebecca, now it seems the links to answers work too? I'm confused. Please see update of my question.

Comment: @Tomas (or anyone else arriving here with that question) see the 2012-01-10 entry in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/307622).  Answer links now count as well as question links.