# What "visitors" count towards the publicity badges?

Tags: support, badges, views, publicity-badges

I was just thinking about these badges and how exactly your number of visitors is calculated. Really, this boils down into three key groups which you could gain counts from:

- **New visitors**: Those who are viewing it for the first time, never seen it before.
- **Old visitors**: Those who have viewed it before, but not via your referral link.
- **Bots**: Automated services that just crawl links.

So thinking about this, what visitors actually count towards the badges? Do they have to be new visitors which haven't been counted in the views total for the question yet? Do bots count? Theoretically everyone could get ~10 easy views just by posting the link *anywhere* and letting Google, Yahoo, etc crawl their link and "view" the page, even though they may have already crawled and indexed that page many, many times before that.

The only thing I've seen is that referral hits that come from the Stack Exchange network do not count. Is there any other kind of limitation?

Comment: Can you link to the source that linking from within the StackExchange network does not count?

Comment: @Jim: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114608/141525 - I'm sure it's been mentioned other places as well, but she's staff.

Comment: Would you happen to know this now that you’re staff?