# How are views for the Popular Question badge counted?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What “visitors” count towards the publicity badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121475/what-visitors-count-towards-the-publicity-badges)

How are views for the [Popular Question badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question) counted? Would me clicking on one of my own questions, logged in as me, count as a view?

before click, from my profile to my own question

[image]

after (views are increased)

[image]

Comment: It's very very conservative (probably 1 view tops per IP?), but you viewing your own question does seem to count as a view. One single view no matter how many times you view it (from the same PC/IP of course)

Comment: @mKorbel That is what the question says...

Comment: @Ben Brocka conservative like as voting to Q&A twice :-)