# Do search engine crawling bots count toward view counts?

Tags: discussion, questions, views

When questions are asked on SO, I'm sure they are constantly being cached by web crawlers; do these count toward the "viewed" counter on question pages? Or does SO at least *try* to fish those out?

Comment: This is a great opportunity to advertise my [old but related and still unanswered question about visitors](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121475/what-visitors-count-towards-the-publicity-badges).

Answer (score 6):

No, they do not.

We test user-agents and know (well, as long as it's a known web spider user agent) if the HTTP request is coming from a web crawler or not.