# Chat onebox kills referral link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, onebox, referrals

Today, I just realized that when you onebox a link in chat, the referral tail is removed.

For example, if I try to onebox `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/178438`, it [links to](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1024163#1024163) `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts` ([Evidence that I used a referral link](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/1024163/history))

Could this be fixed? Sharing a link in chat obviously counts as "shared a link".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publicity badges are designed [not to count clicks on links that are shared within the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114608/137537):

> The link must be clicked from outside the network in order for it to count for this purpose.

Since our in-house chat is part of the network, having the onebox link to the share URL would only result in a wasted redirect that won't count towards the publicity badges, so the system just rewrites the share URL into the normal URL instead.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. Explains why I don't have any of those badges.