# Pasting links into chat won't support "Announcer" badge

Tags: support, status-bydesign, chat, hyperlinks, publicity-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chat onebox kills referral link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139912/chat-onebox-kills-referral-link)

When I post a link into chat (as in xttp://security.stackexchange.com/q/24810/396) , in a single line by itself, the chat software will reformat that URL with a summary, then it changes the URL to a "Direct link", namely it also loses the "/396" on the end of the URL.

I believe this means that pasting links into chat will not give anyone the announcer badge.

Is this correct and the way it should be?  Should this be corrected?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You have to share the link [**outside the Stack Exchange network**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78160/how-does-the-announcer-badge-work) in order for the visits to count towards the badges.

Comment: @animuson I think at a minimum the announcer badge should work **between sites** so SE Beta sites can get more hits

Comment: You're supposed to spam links from outside the house

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges is to promote the site to people who don't use Stack Exchange. People on Stack Exchange are already here, and they already see the sites listed in the footer, global inbox, and ads in the sidebar.

The badges are awarded for helping to build the network, and if you're just sharing links within the network, you're dealing in blue money. This would be like your IT department charging your Accounting department for IT support services. The money only changes hands on paper, and no growth results from this action.

With that said, don't let this stop you from sharing links in chat or encouraging users to visit a beta site you're trying to promote. The reward there should be that you've helped grow something that you're invested in. If you happen to get a badge as well, so be it, but don't let that be all that drives you. ;)