# Update publicity badge descriptions - they work for answers as well as for questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, publicity-badges

The 'share a link' badges ([Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer), [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster) and [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist)) work for [answers as well as questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123544/295232). This is [reflected in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188733/295232) but not in the badge descriptions:

[image]

Can this please be changed to

> Share a link to a question or one of its answers later visited by X unique IP addresses

Comment: I think saying "question or answer" makes it even more confusing, because it makes it sound like the badge can be awarded to answers also, which isn't true. I think the FAQ clarifying that answer links contribute towards the count for the parent question makes more sense.

Comment: Ah, you mean that when I share two different links to a question (the Q and one A, or two separate As) they'll count *together* for an Announcer badge to the *question*. Maybe the new wording is better – it's more clear that the badge is awarded for the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We were notified of a [bug in the badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339664/164200) and during our investigation, we decided that it made more sense to have these badges be tied to `Post` instead of `Question`. All of the badge descriptions have been updated to:

> Share a link to a post

More details on the change are [available in my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340289/164200).