# Suddenly getting "Announcer" badges every few minutes?

Tags: support, badges, publicity-badges

The first one was unusual, but not too unusual.

The second one was improbable, but not impossible.

The third one made me ask this...

[image]

Is there a bug giving me these all of a sudden?

Comment: Nope. Fixed a bug. :D https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339664/missing-publicist-badge

Comment: @Catija Ah, that make sense.

Comment: Indeed! Enjoy the wealth of badges. ;)

Comment: Given all of the bugs I've seen today I'm so glad this is the opposite.