# Publicity badge descriptions not updated everywhere

Tags: bug, badges, achievements-dialog, publicity-badges

The badge description for the publicity badges like Announcer have recently been updated: [Update publicity badge descriptions - they work for answers as well as for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322931/295232). This is reflected in the Achievements inbox:

[image]

However, the inbox in the Stack Exchange iOS app still uses the old description, referring to 'question' instead of 'post':

[image]

I'm curious how this could happen - do the badge descriptions need to be updated separately in the API system? Or are they cached somehow?

Comment: Looks like it has been updated now - at least for me. So maybe a caching issue after all? I did restart the app before reporting the bug.