# How long do the "share" links last?

Tags: discussion, permalink, share-this

I want to add a link to Stack Overflow as a "See this for more information".  I clicked the "Share" link and put that URL in the comments of my code.

But then I realized, that is not the main URL to the page, which got me wondering if that link will be recycled/deleted eventually.

**What is the lifecycle of a "Share" link on Stack Overflow?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It never expires.

The link contains your own user ID in addition to the main URL: this is what allows the system to count how many people followed the link, so you can get the [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer)/[Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster)/[Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) badges.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114621/325443) is an answer with details on how share links are built.

A more complete reference on how all Stack Exchange URLs are constructed has been compiled by Glorfindel [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332251/325443) (see "questions short form" and "answers short form").

Comment: `https://<meta if applicable>.<sitename>.com/q/<post_id>/<user_id>` for questions, `https://<meta if applicable>.<sitename>.com/a/<post_id>/<user_id>` for users. And yes, a link without user_id still works, it's only used for referral purposes IIRC. Post_id is unique, so there's no reason to let it expire. It will always point to the same post, even if the post is removed.

Comment: Of-course, when the question is removed and you don't have sufficient privileges, you'll reach a 404 page instead of the question. If the answer is removed and you don't have sufficient privileges, you'll land somewhere else on that question's page.