# How does the question page view/hit work?

Tags: discussion, bug, views, publicity-badges

[I got an Announcer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer?userid=341929) for a [question that has only been **viewed 12 times**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9945152/341929), yet:

> *Announcer*: Shared a link to a question that was visited by **25 unique IP addresses**.

How does the question page view/hit work?

Answer (score 6):

Its been mentioned on both the SE blog and postcasts that the view counter on SE is conservative. So its likely your real view count is between 24 and 36 (before the meta post)

From [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/)

> The cartoon question alone had over a million views by our **extremely
> strict view counter** — which easily translates to at least two million
> views, possibly three million

On the other hand the link tracking [is defined in this answer from Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64030/148672)

> It doesn't matter whether incoming visitors have an account or not,
> what matters is that the IP is unique and the shared link was clicked
> outside our network

There's clearly a difference between the view counter and the shared links counter and I suspect they won't release the exact algorithm for the view counter because people might try and get around it to get their question more attention by making it a hot question or to get one of the view based badges.

Answer (score -5):

The number of views on the page is **cached**. I see it as ***25*** now.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. Those views were probably because of this meta question.

Comment: No, @lunboks is right. It definitely said "16" when I looked at it a minute or so after this question was posted.

Comment: I agree with **@lunboks** and **@TheEstablishment**: it was 12 when I asked, then it gradually grew with time, but it was still <25 for quite a while.