# Received "Announcer" badge, question only shows 21 views

Tags: bug, badges, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the question page view/hit work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127574/how-does-the-question-page-view-hit-work)

As of right now I have 21 views (I'm sure it will go up after this post) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404191/database-architecture-quantity-splitting) but I received an [announcer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer?userid=7173) for it this morning. Are views just slow to sync?