# Can we get the short/tracked permalink on answers too?

Tags: feature-request, answers, permalink, short-links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show a short link for Answers too… not just Questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/show-a-short-link-for-answers-too-not-just-questions)

I was just copying and pasting a link from from one of my answers using the "link" text below it.  After pasting it and posting it, I suddenly remembered the new tracking thing.  My link looked like this:

> [JavaScript killing a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214379/javascript-killing-a-process/2214467#2214467)

Can we get the shorter permalinks on the answers?  I know the shorter links work just fine, it's just a matter of changing the url for the permalink link.

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/2214467/94197

Comment: @ChrisF: couldn't find that.  Oh well... status-declined is a bit of a bummer.

Comment: I could only find it because I knew it existed. It didn't show up in a search for the terms you used in your title.