# Are there any ways to share links to answers, the homepage, or tags page that is tracked?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hyperlinks

It sounds to me like the tracked external linking methods only apply to questions or answers.  So if you are sharing links to go toward getting the Announcer/Booster/Publicist badges, the only options apparently are sharing permalinks or using the facebook/twitter/other buttons on questions.

Why doesn't answers have the same linkability?  Or even the homepage?  Is this even available?  If not, can it be made available?

I can't seem to find any links on the homepage or other links to do so and I don't think simply adding my userid the way it is now to it would even work.

I can see potential opportunities to share links to Stack Overflow (or any other Stack Exchange site) where I don't want to link to a specific question or answer.  I want to be able to say to people I'm helping, "If you have any more programming questions, http://www.stackoverflow.com is a great resource." and have it tracked.

---

And why stop there?  It would be very nice to have these links for the tag pages as well.  So if I'm directing others in a particular discipline or programming language, I could direct them to these questions pre-filtered.

Comment: There could be links like stackoverflow.com/ref/uniqueusernumber which on being used could give you the Publicist badge. For eg. 10 referrals would earn you a Bronze, fifty a Silver and 100 a Gold badge. Is it really needed, I cannot say. (Thank God for delete)

Comment: I added the publicity tag.

Answer (score 3):

In all honesty, the questions and answers are the "meat" of the site and that's what we want shared. In other words, it makes the internet better to say

> I see you're having trouble with `String.Format` and percentages, http://example.com/questions/12345/how-to-use-string-format has a great answer for that

than

> If you have any more programming questions, http://www.example.com is a great resource

I'd be more open to extending this to answers, like so

[Show a short link for Answers too... not just Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/show-a-short-link-for-answers-too-not-just-questions)

Comment: Ah, I forgot that answers didn't contain the tracking info.  Add that to my request then.  :)

Comment: The particular scenarios I'm usually in are where I'm tutoring under some programming language.  So typically I'd be getting many questions on varying topics.  I love providing answers when I know them.  When I don't (which doesn't happen much at all), I'd see myself searching here and summarize providing a link to a similar question/answer here.  However that works when people have a specific question.  When I'm not available or when the session is over, I'd use the line I had up above in the question.  In my case, I'd make more use of the links to the general site, more than to specific q's.