# "Shared a link" to an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, hyperlinks, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any ways to share links to answers, the homepage, or tags page that is tracked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74831/are-there-any-ways-to-share-links-to-answers-the-homepage-or-tags-page-that-is)

On [judaism.se], post 8472 is a question, and 8473 is one of its answers.

I understand the "shared a link to a question" badges are handed out when links like `https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8472/503` are followed sufficiently. If links like `https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8473/503` (which [do work](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8473/503)) are followed, do those also count toward the badges?

- If not, I suggest they do.
- If so:

  1. Do the two links above count toward a single badge (since they are to the same question)?
  2. The "link" link beneath each answer should include the trailing user-identifier.

Comment: Ah, now I see that half of this is a duplicate of [the post it's marked a duplicate of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74831), and the other half is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841. Sorry about that.

Comment: It [does work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64030#comment-152481), counts towards the question in the same way as the first link, and adding links in the appropriate form to answers is [currently `status-declined`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63841), though as mentioned in Jeff's answer on the above-linked duplicate, potentially open for reconsideration.