# Shorter answer links

Tags: feature-request, answers, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show a short link for Answers too… not just Questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/show-a-short-link-for-answers-too-not-just-questions)

On a question, the link button gives me this URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6490844/39321
```

On the same question, the link button on an answer gives me this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490844/real-world-example-of-how-to-structure-the-mvc-part-of-an-already-existing-websit/6493997#6493997
```

Please change this? Would be so much nicer if it could give me this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6490844/39321#6493997
```

This works, is much shorter and includes my userid (which I believe is used for something when others use my link?)

Either way, please give me shorter answer links :(