# Offer long links to answers, in addition to just short

Tags: feature-request, answers, hyperlinks

Let's say you are looking at [some question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache/37013954) and you see a good answer, and you want to share it with your friends.

Well, each answer only has short links available. If you want a long link that looks clearer to your friends, well, you'll just have to visit the short link yourself, and then copy the resultant long link out of the browser's URL bar, and share that.

Yes, years ago the problem was [the opposite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96586/shorter-answer-links). But now they over-corrected it.

Comment: Ctrl/cmd-clicking the "share" link (or right-clicking and choosing to open it in a new tab) may save you one step. But I agree it probably wouldn't be a terrible idea to make both long and short links an option in the "share" pop-up (perhaps as separate tabs?).