# The new /a/ referral short links aren't included in robots.txt

Tags: bug, status-completed

[Stack Exchange's `robots.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) includes the existing short links URLs starting with `/q/` and `/u/`, but hasn't been updated to include [the new referral short links for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/show-a-short-link-for-answers-too-not-just-questions) starting with `/a/`.

Comment: Yikes. Google indexed a *lot* of these: [inurl:http://stackoverflow.com/a/](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl:http://stackoverflow.com/a/&filter=0). Fortunately I don't think they come up too easily in normal search results.

Comment: Oh, my bad - those results aren't actually indexed. Google just knows they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, nice catch, thanks! Added to the next build.